First draggable item is not on top of other items in a Row while it's dragged on Jetpack Compose
I have a collection of five items, all of which are draggable. I want to achieve behavior in which the dragged item will overlap all the others. I tried changing the zIndex parameter but it didn't work, what am I doing wrong?
item code:
@Composable
fun <T> DragTarget(
dataToDrop: T,
content: @Composable () -> Unit) {

var dragOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
var currentPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(Rect.Zero) }
val currentState = LocalDragTargetInfo.current

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .zIndex(if (currentState.isDragging) 5f else 0f) // my first try
        .offset {
            IntOffset(
                dragOffset.x.roundToInt(),
                dragOffset.y.roundToInt()
            )
        }
        .onGloballyPositioned { layout ->
            layout
                .boundsInWindow()
                .let { rect ->
                    currentPosition = rect
                }
        }
        .pointerInput(dataToDrop) {
            detectDragGestures(
                onDragStart = {
                    currentState.isDragging = true
                    currentState.dataToDrop = dataToDrop
                    currentState.dragPosition = currentPosition
                },
                onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()
                    dragOffset += dragAmount
                    currentState.dragPosition = currentPosition
                },
                onDragEnd = {
                    currentState.isDragging = false
                    dragOffset = Offset.Zero
                    currentState.dragPosition = Rect.Zero
                }
            )
        },
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    content()
}}

item collection code
@Composable
fun TestView() {
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp, alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    DragTarget(dataToDrop = null) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.zIndex(5f) // my second try
                         .size(50.dp).background(Color.Blue))
    }
    DragTarget(dataToDrop = null) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp).background(Color.Green))
    }
    DragTarget(dataToDrop = null) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp).background(Color.LightGray))
    }
    DragTarget(dataToDrop = null) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp).background(Color.Yellow))
    }
    DragTarget(dataToDrop = null) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp).background(Color.Red))
    }
}}

and my DragTargetInfo:
class DragTargetInfo {
var isDragging by mutableStateOf(false)
var dragPosition by mutableStateOf(Rect.Zero)
var dataToDrop by mutableStateOf<Any?>(null)}

val LocalDragTargetInfo = compositionLocalOf { DragTargetInfo() }

I will be grateful for any tips as I have been trying to untangle this tangle for several days now and achieve the desired result. Peace to all friends)

How is it now? Draggable item is behind other items while it's dragged?

yes he's still behind(

Where is the source of LocalDragTargetInfo?

I added source of LocalDragTargetInfo

I edited my answer, now it's even simpler. First I unnecessarily over-engineered it.

One solution is moving zIndex into a state variable and making it independent of the currentState.isDragging and changing its value directly on onDragStart and onDragEnd lambdas.
@Composable
fun <T> DragTarget(
    dataToDrop: T,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    var dragOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    var currentPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(Rect.Zero) }
    val currentState = LocalDragTargetInfo.current

    var zIndex by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .zIndex(zIndex)
            .offset {
                IntOffset(
                    dragOffset.x.roundToInt(),
                    dragOffset.y.roundToInt()
                )
            }
            .onGloballyPositioned { layout ->
                layout
                    .boundsInWindow()
                    .let { rect ->
                        currentPosition = rect
                    }
            }
            .pointerInput(dataToDrop) {
                detectDragGestures(
                    onDragStart = {
                        currentState.isDragging = true
                        currentState.dataToDrop = dataToDrop
                        currentState.dragPosition = currentPosition
                        zIndex = 1f
                    },
                    onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                        change.consume()
                        dragOffset += dragAmount
                        currentState.dragPosition = currentPosition
                    },
                    onDragEnd = {
                        currentState.isDragging = false
                        dragOffset = Offset.Zero
                        currentState.dragPosition = Rect.Zero
                        zIndex = 0f
                    }
                )
            },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
fun TestView() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
            16.dp,
            alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        DragTarget(dataToDrop = "Blue") {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            )
        }
        DragTarget(dataToDrop = "Green") {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.Green)
            )
        }
        DragTarget(dataToDrop = "Gray") {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
            )
        }
        DragTarget(dataToDrop = "Yellow") {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )
        }
        DragTarget(dataToDrop = "Red") {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }
    }
}

